# Parse.com Backup Retention

Tags: parse-platform

According to Fosco, Parse does its own data backup in the rare event that Parse causes some data to be lost.  Is there a stated policy for how long these backups are kept?  I am asking because if a user of my application wants their account deleted and I delete all of their data from my database.  How long will the last snapshot of it in Parse's own backups remain?

I do realize that these backup are not for on-demand recovery but the fact that the data still exists means I need to account for it.

Thanks!